# Loop in array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I am writing a code with array of pointers and structures.
Code is:

```
struct Student_List{
    int roll;
    char name[20];
    int mark1;
    int mark2;
    int mark3;
    struct Student_List *next;
};
struct Student_List *Class[] = { NULL };// to generate student's list for various classes.
struct Student_List *current =NULL;

struct Student_List * check(int rollNo, int classNo)
{

struct Student_List *temp=NULL;
temp=Class[classNo];

while (temp!=NULL) {
    if(temp->rollNo == rollNo)
    {
        //element is found
        return temp;
    }

    temp = temp->next;
}    
if(temp==NULL)
{
    //element not found
    return NULL;
}
//scan serially and if found return address of that node
//if no element found return NULL

}

//add elements to list pointed by Class
struct Student_List * add(char studentName, int rollNo,int classNo)
{
    struct Studen_List *newNode=(struct Student_List *)malloc(sizeof(struct Student_List ));
if (newNode == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        }  

newNode->roll=rollNo;
strcpy(newNode->name,studentName);
newNode->mark1=0;
newNode->mark2=0;
newNode->mark3=0;
struct Student_List *temp = NULL, *previous = NULL;

temp=Class[classNo];
prev = temp;
}

if(temp==NULL)
{
    Class[classNo]=newNode;
    return Class[classNo];


}

while(temp!=NULL)
{
    prev=temp;
    temp=temp->next;
}

prev->next=newNode;
return newNode;
//add node to end of the list
}

void Delete_List(struct Student_List *temp)
{
delete []temp;
//temp = NULL;

/*while(temp!=NULL)
{
    struct Student_List *del=temp;
    temp=temp->next;
    free(del);

}*/
}

int main();
{
int classNo,rollNo,i;
char *name;

printf("\nEnter Class No: ");
scanf("%d",&classNo);
printf("\nEnter Name: ")
gets(name);
printf("\nEnter Roll No: ");
scanf("%d",&rollNo);


current = check(rollNo,classNo);

if(current == NULL){
current = add(name,rollNo,classNo);
}
// others is the marks data fetched from file and calculations.
// this code is enough to reproduce my error.

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    Delete_List(Class[i]);
}
  return;
}
```

Problem:
When I assign values and perform Calculation, results were wrong. On debugging I found that my `Class[3]`'s starting address is same as `Class[1]->nextRoll->nextRoll;`

I am unable to remove it. Please help me to remove loop.
any help with syntax or suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: The code doesn't compile, doesn't even have the "loop" you need help removing. You want us to help you with a code unrelated to your problem? Here's one: `int main() { }`, this one works.

Comment: It'll be useful to show us how you initialising and using `Class`.

Comment: Is this C++ or C? Pick only one.

Comment: @DanielKO : Don't panic dear. loop is in address as mentioned in problem. and ur solution is welcomed, but i already know that.

Comment: You have to struggle with your problem first by learning and reading more ,using some well known books and website could help you lot.
Then ask your question if its not clear or not mention else where.

Comment: @Thanushan BalaKrishnan: I had posted the code

Comment: @AmirNaghizadeh I had done research that's why i am posting here. No array of pointers topic suggests what to do if u r getting loop in memory addresses. If u found any article related to that, or any article that u think can help me, please provide me its link. I'll be really thankful to u.

Answer (score 2):

You shall not use `malloc`, use `new`:

```
struct Student_List{
    int roll;
    char name[20];
    int mark1;
    int mark2;
    int mark 3;
    Student_List *nextRoll;
};

Student_List * Class[] = { NULL };

int main();
{
    // various initializations

    // for each new student, do this
    Student_List *newNode=new Student_List;
    newNode->next = Class[0]; // 0 is the Class of the student
    Class[0] = newNode;

    // code to fetch data from text file and perform calculations.

    // do not delete Class; !!
}
```

Note that your approach is wrong, you should use the STL as much as possible. Example:

```
struct Student {
    int roll;
    std::string name;
    int mark1;
    int mark2;
    int mark3;
};

typedef std::list< Student > Class;

typedef std::map< std::string, Class > Classes;
Classes classes;

int main()
{
    Student s;
    s.name = "Daniel";
    // ...

    classes[ "1b" ].push_back( s ); // Add student to a class "1b".
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. and I know that STL will be more useful, but unfortunately, I don't know it. though I had started learning it, but due to some boundations, i have to complete this code as suggested by the previous person working on it.